# How to assign constant inside a class like const TITLENAME = $titlename?

Tags: php

I need to declare const inside the class ie a variable to the const value (const VAR = $var;).
I need substitute a Key from Json in Myfile.json to the constant inside the class

Comment: Downvote for not doing any research yourself.

Comment: Your read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) and you will get everything you want.

Comment: I need substitute a Key from Json in Myfile.json to the constant inside the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass value to your constant via [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

```
<?php

    class Test {

        const TESTCONST = '';

        function __construct($const_value) {
            $this->TESTCONST = $const_value;
        }
    }

$test = new Test('testvalue');
echo $test->TESTCONST;
```

Return:

`testvalue`

**Notice** that you cannot use name of const `VAR`. **Also notice**, that CONST is something you want to use without changing it.

Comment: unfortunatelly `echo Test::TESTCONST;` still gives ''

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea of a constant is that the value does not change (hence the name).
Read more about it here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

I would suggest you use public/protected/private properties in combination with getters and setters (depending on your needs of course).